# How can I butcher non-tame animals that I've captured?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How can I butcher non-tame animals that I've captured, like deer in cages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-tame animals are bugged in 31.12 such that if they need to be moved more than a few steps, the dwarves carrying them panic, drop them, and flee, freeing the wild animal (or goblin) and causing chaos.

In addition to this, I believe the "slaughter an animal" task only applies to tame animals. "butcher a dead animal" is how you handle hunted animals, but this is hard given the abovementioned bug.

a) -- throw the animals into a pit. The pit must be as close to the cage with the animal as possible. once you have successfully "pitted" the animal, your marksdwarves / hunters can dispatch it at their leisure.

b) -- build the cage into a room, link it to a lever, station your military, and have someone pull the lever. Military will kill the animal, and then your butcher will run over and grab the corpse.

Comment: No, he won't. Butchers will only butcher animals they themselves have killed, check the wiki.

Comment: @Arda Xi, I'm sorry, but you're wrong. The wiki may be a great source, but it is also occasionally outdated or outrightly false. I am currently playing a fort where I send my wrestlers out to punch unicorns to death. The dwarves then bring the corpse to a refuse pile, whereupon my butcher grabs the carcass, and the next thing you know it's Unicorn Brain Biscuits for everyone!

Comment: @Raven - For me, it's never been possible to harvest corpses. Are you using 31.12?

Comment: @Arda Xi, yes. Is your problem that you kill something outside the fort? In that case, you might need to o - r - "dwarves gather refuse from outside" so that they will leave your cozy fort and go grab the corpse.

Comment: @Raven - No, actually, it was inside. They won't go on to the refuse pile for meat.

Comment: @Arda Xi, Odd. I haven't had that problem at all. I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: I can butcher some, but it takes a while. I haven't tried it with a dedicated butcher. Also, while you are right that you can't move animals, you can move goblins/humans as long as they aren't thieves. I use this for executing the ones in my cage traps.

Comment: Since there is obviously some kind of competition in getting the strangest title on a Dwarf Fortress question, can I say that my vote would unquestionably go to anyone writing a question including the phrase "I send my wrestlers out to punch unicorns to death".

Comment: Bwaha! Excellent.